# Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, nodemailer

## Introduction

I'm working on an app that uses firebase as the database(RealTime Database). We use firebase-admin on the backend (A REST API built on Node Express) only for operations that require admin permissions such as User Authentication, User Account Deletion or the likes.

### Summary of problem

So, what i am trying to do is, the user who is being approved by admin, it's status should change to true as it's status was pending. So the code given below filter's out specific user and look for the user in database and changes approve status to true.I have commented the code which is handling database operation.

#### Problem :

I am facing two problems here :

1. If I keep the database operation code commented, and if there is a new registration, then two mails are send to user from admin. First is 'registration is successful' and second 'error during registraion' (Which should not happen as per code).
2. If i remove the comments of database operation,the following error occurs :

> Error (while running) :@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback.
>
> Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times.
> Please make sure the format of the database URL matches with each database() call.

The Code is as following :

```
router.get('/approval', (req, res) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            let errors = [];
            var k = 0;
            var email = req.query.email;
            var keys = Object.keys(userData);
            console.log("email : " + email);
            for (k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                console.log("user email : " + userData.email[k]);
                if (!(email.localeCompare(userData.email[k]))) {

                    console.log("user email : " + userData.email[k]);
                    var password = userData.password[k];
                    console.log("password taken ");
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .then(function (user) {
            console.log("inside firebase");

            //Code to change user's approval status to true

                          
            /*  var reference = require('../DatabaseRef/reference'); 
                var ref = reference.usersRef;
                ref.on('value', gotData, errData);
                 function gotData(data) {
                 var userData = data.val();
                 if (userData != null) {
                     var keys = Object.keys(userData);
                     var newPostKey = keys[k]; 
              
                                                 
          firebase.database().ref().child('/BMS/UserDetails/' + newPostKey)
          .update({ approve: true });
              
                        }
                 }    
              
           function errData(err) {
                           console.log(err);
                       }
                                                  
                                             */
                            
                            
                            
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
         service: 'gmail', 
         auth: {
                user: '**********@gmail.com', 
                pass: '**********'
                }
         });

      let mailOptions = {
        from: '********@gmail.com', 
        to: email,
        subject: "Registration Successful", 
        text: "Registration is complete ,now you can try logging in through 
               link given below :.", 
        html: "<a href='http://localhost:5005/'>Login</a> " 
                            };

             transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
                                if (err)
                                    console.log(err)
                                else
                                    console.log(info);
                            });

                            errors.push({ msg: "Registered Successfully" });
                            res.render('./addUser', { userData, errors });


                        })
                         
      .catch(function (error) {
                            var errorCode = error.code;
                            var errorMessage = error.message;
                           

                            console.log("inside catch");

                            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                                service: 'gmail', 
                                auth: {
                                    user: '*********@gmail.com', 
                                    pass: '**********' 
                                }
                            });

                           
        let mailOptions = {
          from: '**********@gmail.com', 
          to: email, // list of receivers
          subject: "Error during user registration", 
          text: "Error Found : " + errorMessage, 
          html: "<a href='http://localhost:5005/signup'>Register</a> " 
               
           };

                        
       transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
            if (err)
                 console.log(err)
             else
                   console.log(info);
            });
       
       errors.push({ msg: errorMessage });
       res.render('./addUser', { userData, errors });

          })

                    break;
                }
            }
            console.log("out of for loop");
        }

        else {
            console.log("User not present");
            res.redirect('/')
        }

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Database Fatal error,this worked for me :

```
var db = admin.database();
db.ref("Path till child"+newPostKey).update({approve : true});
```

In this case path till child = "BMS/UserDetails/"